# convert to array from database sql php

Tags: php, arrays, explode

```
<?php   
$content = "my content";
$parts = array("Part 1 :", "Part 2 :", "Part 3 :","Part 4 :", "Part 5 :");
$name_list = array("Part 1 :\n", "Part 2 :\n", "Part 3 :\n","Part 4 :\n", "Part 5 :");

$email_body = "Product:\n" .str_replace($parts, $name_list, $content);
?>
```

How I can obtain the same result as in the first script, but I want to import the second array `$name_list` from my database.

I did the script below, but it doesn't work.

```
<?php 
$query  = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE  id LIKE '%$id%'";
$search = mysql_query($query ) or die(mysql_error());

$name_list = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($search)) {
    $name_list[] = $row['name'] . ":\n,";
}
$name_list = explode(", ", $name_list);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove this line `$name_list = explode(",",$name_list);`, because `$name_list`  already in array, and you can use explode to convert string to array, e.g..

```
<?php
    $name_list = "Part 1 :\n, Part 2 :\n, Part 3 :\n, Part 4 :\n, Part 5 :";
    $name_list = explode(",", $name_list);
    print_r($name_list);
?>
```

output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Part 1 :

    [1] =>  Part 2 :

    [2] =>  Part 3 :

    [3] =>  Part 4 :

    [4] =>  Part 5 :
)
```

so try below code

```
<?php 
$query  = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE  id LIKE '%$id%'";
$search = mysql_query($query ) or die(mysql_error());


$name_list = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($search)) {
    $name_list[] = $row['name'].":\n,";
}

$parts = array("Part 1 :", "Part 2 :", "Part 3 :","Part 4 :", "Part 5 :");

$email_body = "Product:\n" .str_replace($parts, $name_list, $content);

?>
```

Comment: remove  this line   <code>   $name_list = explode(",",$name_list);</code> only, because explode require string, but your passing array